# Searching an Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that is being grabbed from my database that outputs the following when it is print_r

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Administrator ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Events Organiser ) )
```

How would I go about searching that array to see if it contained the words 'Events Organiser'?

I know if it was a standard array setup like

```
Array ( [0] => Administrator ) [1] => Events Organiser ) )
```

then I could use the in_array but this doesn't seem to work with the way my array is output.

Comment: You probably want to do that in the SQL query because it can be faster.

Comment: i think you can make a validation like if($result[1] == 'Events Organizer'){...}

Comment: But I need it to check all the values not just 1. The Events Organiser on another array could be in the first position.

Comment: Just loop the results and when find what you looking for break from loop.

Comment: I went with your option of looping it around. Was the only way I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

array_search will do this, example is as follow

```
<?php
$your_array = array(key=>values);

$key = array_search('value_for_search', $your_array); 

 ?>
```

Comment: I can't set the array as key=>values. It is being output as above from a WP class.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding your array

```
$std = new stdClass();
$std->name = "Administrator";

$std2 = new stdClass();
$std2->name = "Events Organiser";

$array = array($std,$std2);
```

You can use

```
$find = "Events Organiser" ;
$list = array_filter($array,function($v) use ($find) { return $v->name == $find ; });
var_dump($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` lets you specify a custom function to do the searching. In your case, a simple function that uses `strpos()` to check if your search string is present:

```
function my_search($targetval) {
    $srch_val= 'value to search';
    return(strpos($targetval, $srch_val)); // or stripos() if you want case-insensitive searching.
}

$matches = array_filter($your_array, 'my_search');
```

for further reference you can see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)